# Error creating cx_freeze package with boto3 in windows, missing configparser import

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze, boto3

I'm working on Pycharm in Windows using python 3.4.3 32bit version. There I import boto3.

When running on the IDE all is fine, however when I try yo generate a .exe with cx_freeze, boto3 appears to fail with the following stack trace.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "c:/Users/Rui/PycharmProjects/VOConverter/upload_aws.py", line 1, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\site-packages\boto3\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\site-packages\boto3\session.py", line 17, in <module>
    import botocore.session
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\site-packages\botocore\session.py", line 25, in <module>
    import botocore.config
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\site-packages\botocore\config.py", line 19, in <module>
    from six.moves import configparser
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2281, in _handle_fromlist
  File "C:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
    result = self._resolve()
  File "C:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
    return _import_module(self.mod)
  File "C:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\python\32-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'configparser'
```

I cannot install configparser via pip3.exe, but in any case the code works fine if run from PyCharm or via the command line. The error from pip3 is:

```
Collecting configparser
  Using cached configparser-3.3.0r2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
      File "c:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
        import distutils.core
      File "c:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 18, in <module>
        from distutils.config import PyPIRCCommand
      File "c:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\distutils\config.py", line 7, in <module>
        from configparser import ConfigParser
      File "C:\Users\Rui\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-rjnpk61m\configparser\configparser.py", line 397
        _KEYCRE = re.compile(ur"%\(([^)]+)\)s")
                                             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also the versions on my system:

```
python 3.4.3

pip 7.1.2 from c:\tools\pythonx86_32\lib\site-packages (python 3.4)

Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: boto3
Version: 1.2.3
```

Really stumped on this one. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using pyinstaller instead of cx_freeze solved the issue.